# parallel_invoke same method in tbb

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

can I use parallel_invoke to execute the same function  multiple times

like I have function scan which traverse a string can I make the same multiple tasks operate on it.

Comment: Maybe you could add some pseudo code describing what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Alternatively you can use a task_group:

```
tbb::task_group g;
g.run(foo);
g.run(foo);

g.wait();
```

If you want to run it as often as you have CPU-cores, you can do it like this:

```
tbb::task_group g;

for(auto i = 0; i != tbb::tbb_thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
    g.run(foo);
}

g.wait();
```

Comment: I want to ask do you need to #include <task_scheduler_init.h>

Comment: @aTm no, you only need that if you explicitly start the task-scheduler which you are supposed not to do.

Comment: @aTm note that you can upvote and accept answers, especially if you found them helpful and could use their code.

Comment: @StephanDollberg he's new here, so I've upvoted for him :P (he's at least accepted the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nothing will stop you, but you're responsible for determining whether those actions will cause race conditions or concurrency issues that will blow up your program.